# How can I tell if the USB Installer created by Startup Disk Creator is UEFI?

Tags: partitioning, uefi, live-usb

I want to do a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 on a 2TB NVMe SSD, and I want to create the partitions manually and install the OS in UEFI. Just wanting to know if the default USB installer that Startup Disk Creator makes is UEFI by default, or if I have to make it so.

Comment: The default Ubuntu ISO does both, and Startup Disk Creator carries that along (I think).  Some ISO burners will let you select legacy vs.UEFI, but I usually just use dd to burn a USB from an ISO.

Comment: When you clone from the Ubuntu iso file to a USB drive, it can install both in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) and UEFI mode. The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator is a cloning tool. - You decide how Ubuntu is installed by the boot mode that you select: If you boot in BIOS mode, Ubuntu will be installed in BIOS mode, else if you boot in UEFI mode, Ubuntu will be installed in UEFI mode. This decision is made very early in the boot process, before Ubuntu (on the USB drive) is involved, and you should check it and maybe change it via a UEFI/BIOS menu.

Comment: If you need help to get into the UEFI/BIOS menu system, please tell us about your computer: brand name and model (or if home-built: brand name and model of your motherboard). - When you have booted into Ubuntu live booted from the USB drive, you can check the boot mode by the following command line (in a terminal window), `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`

Comment: Thanks much. That makes it clear. Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

The default USB Ubuntu installation media that Startup Disk Creator makes is UEFI by default. It will be bootable on all computers that use the UEFI firmware.

Startup Disk Creator will automatically create an EFI partition on the USB flash drive which contains the files that are necessary for the computer to boot from the USB flash drive.